# GridSummaryItem in DxGrid not updating when cell has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, devexpress

I'm working with a DxGrid and I've added a summary field to the bottom:

```
        <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="MyField" SummaryType="Sum"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
```

It works fine except for the fact that the summary field is not updated unless i move focus out from the row that's been updated. I don't know if this behavior is by design, but either way I doubt it's the most expected, clearly you want the summary to update as soon as the constituent cell has been changed.

Does anyone know why I am seeing this behavior, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of your task is correct, you need to post a new value from the corresponding column immediately after the user changes its value and not on lost focus.
To accompanist this task, you'll need to handle a view's [CellValueChanging](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressWpfGridGridViewBase_CellValueChangingtopic) event and call the view's [PostEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_PostEditortopic) and grid's [UpdateTotalSummary](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_UpdateTotalSummarytopic) methods to force the data update and summary re-evaluation:

```
void TableView_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TableView)sender).PostEditor();
    ((TableView)sender).Grid.UpdateTotalSummary();
}
```